# Apache2 no cache specific file only

Tags: apache, ubuntu, caching, amazon-ec2

I'm running and Amazon EC2 with Ubuntu 14.4 and Apache2 with no PHP or other server-side script--just a static content site.  I used this tutorial to get to the point I am at now with the apache file (see screenshot at link below):
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-content-caching-on-ubuntu-14-04

I want to have a directive (if that is the nomenclature) that tells Apache to not cache a single, specific file only, but still handle everything else as it is already configured.  I'm no computer whizz here--just learning.  Is there a way to do this?  Currently I have made a new directory inside my images folder called "no-cache" where the image I do not want cached lives.

I tried adding a second location tag below the first one with "CacheDisable on" inside it, however this is not supported.  Also tried using a Directory tag, but this also does not work with the current configuration.

Thanks in advance!

[/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000.default.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZwy1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided is a bit confusing since it mentions so many different types of caching.

When dealing with Webservers and caching, what you usually mean is sending cache messages (using http headers) to define how the browser should handle caching, to improve visitors performance. This is the last item discussed in that link of yours, despite being the most common. The first section talks about Apache caching files itself to improve its own performance and is much less common.

If client side caching using mod_expiries is what you mean, then you can control this with location headings:

```
#Allow long term assets to be cached for 6 months as they are versioned and should never change
<Location /assets/libraries/ >
        ExpiresDefault A15724800
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
</Location>

#Do not cache these files
<Location /login >
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache" 
</Location>
```

I've a more detailed blog on this here: https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http-performance-headers/caching/.

Comment: This is perfect!  And what a great post you've got as well!  i finally understand this stuff.  Thank you!!!

Comment: I did have a question regarding the length of the cache for "ExpiresDefault".  604800 is the amount of seconds in one week.  How does this equate to six months?

Comment: It doesn't :-( It's a typo, should be 15724800 - 60 x 60 x 24 x 7 x 26. Corrected answer. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Ah, Ok!  Thanks!  Also, you have the same typo in your tutorial link ;)